# C# multiple increments

Tags: c#

I have, code who do for me "x + y = z"

```
if (command.Contains("+")) // string polecenie = "";'
{
    polecenie = "{" + command + ")";
    polecenie = polecenie.Replace("+", "}(");
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(Between(polecenie, "{", "}"));
    double b = Convert.ToDouble(Between(polecenie, "(", ")"));
    double wyn = a + b;
    richTextBox1.Text += a + " + " + b + " is " + wyn + "\r\n";
}
```

And when 'command' is "4+5","3 + 4" or something like this code works, but when i try to do "4 + 3 + 23" it don't work. Final string with starting 'command' "4+5+6", polecenie is: "{4}(5}(6)"... The Between Method:

```
public string Between(string content, string First, string Last)
{
    string end = "";
    int Plc1 = content.IndexOf(First) + First.Length;
    int Plc2 = content.IndexOf(Last);
    end = content.Substring(Plc1, Plc2 - Plc1);
    return end;
}
```

How can I do that? (I want it to work with all possible additions ("4+4","34+5+54","43+4+65+54"...)

Comment: Why not just split on the "+" to get an array of all the values being added together `var nums = command.Split('+');`  Do you also have to deal with something like "5+3-4*6/7"?

Comment: You'll have to re-think your algorithm. Try splitting the command by `+` instead.

Comment: +juharr Yes, I have also deal with it, and with pow, sqr, log and ln...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataTable object to not re-invent the wheel.

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} is {1}\r\n", command,
    (new System.Data.DataTable()).Compute(command, string.Empty));
```

This would support +, -, *, / and % (mod) operators. For more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Anything more complicated, I would use other libraries. Suggestions I've seen in past are mXparser (http://mathparser.org/) or Jace.net.